# Hiding an dynamic e-mailadress in an dynamic hyperlink

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, email, hyperlink

First time question here and a prog-newbie aswell so i will try to be as clear as possible with my question.
I have Sharepoint 2010 Online and i've been trying to found out a way to connect some site to a third-part-ticket website.
My company have different customers and these customers have a specific customer-site in Sharepoint, aswell as a specific contact person who should be contacted when a ticket is raised.
What i do have at the moment is this;
Specific Customersites in Sharepoint(so the URL for Customer y is like CustomerY.aspx and for Customer X CustomerX.aspx).
I also have a third party web-site with the ticketsystem. The first part of this url is static, whereas the second part is based on what customer is trying to reach that ticketsystem.
I also have a specific contactperson for the specific customers.

Would it be possible(with javascript) to in an hyperlink, link to the customer's specific ticket-system website and at the same time send an e-mail to the choosen contact-person?-

I hope i have made my self as clear as possible.:)
If you have any further questions, please ask.

Comment: you need to provide more info. like the code that you already tried and didn't work, a real/full link, etc.

Comment: you should not do that. **first** try to code something. **later**, come here and ask. read [ask]

Comment: Hi!
I haven't tried that much of code(just been researching on google, trying to find something to work from).
However, the links are; 
https://deltamgmt.sharepoint.com/sites/technical/Pages/Agrando.aspx (The Customer Sharepoint Site, where Agrando is a customer).
and http://rt.deltamanagement.se/Ticket/Create.html?Queue=3&Object-RT::Ticket--CustomField-19-Values=Backbone&Requestors=contact@customer.se is for the ticket-website.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You cannot send an e-mail by executing javascript in the browser.